# Find $\int _{\Gamma} \frac{\cos(2z)}{(z-\pi/4)^2}dz$

Tags: complex-analysis

Where $\Gamma$ consists of the sides of a triangle with vertices $i$, $-1-i$ and $\pi -i$. I think we use Cauchy's integral formula but I cant get it in the standard form of it. I don't think partial fractions would work either..

Please help.

I just tried using the Residue theorem and got $-2$ as the residue of the function at $\pi/4$. So the answer it $-4\pi i$? Is this correct?

It is strange because the first part of the question asked to state Cauchy's integral formula which I thought implies that we should use it to answer this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the Residue Theorem we have

$$\oint_C \frac{\cos 2z}{(z-\pi/4)^2}dz=2\pi i\text{Res}\left(\frac{\cos 2z}{(z-\pi/4)^2},z=\pi/4\right)$$

Since $\cos(2z)=-2(z-\pi/4)+O(z-\pi/4)^3$, the residue is easily seen to be $-2$ and thus

$$\oint_C \frac{\cos 2z}{(z-\pi/4)^2}dz=-4\pi i$$

---

Cauchy's Integral Formula states that

$$f^{(n)}(z)=\frac{n!}{2\pi i}\oint_C\frac{f(z')}{(z'-z)^{n+1}}dz \tag 1$$

Here, $n=1$, $z=\pi/4$, and $f(z) =\cos (2z)$.  Thus, we have that $f'(\pi/4)=-2\sin(2\pi/4)=-2$.  Using $(1)$ we have

$$\oint_C \frac{\cos 2z}{(z-\pi/4)^2}dz=2\pi i(-2)=-4\pi i$$

as expected!

Comment: Just curious, what type of singularity is pi/4? simple pole right?

Comment: @snowman Yes it is pole of order $1$ since $\cos(2z) =O(z-\pi/4)$.